# Django TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: '"{%' from '"{%'

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I am trying to do cycle inside the for loop but it raises error. What is the correct alternative.

```
{% cycle "{% include 'col-1-of-3.html' %}" "{% include 'col-2-of-3.html' %}" "{% include 'col-3-of-3.html' %}" %}
```

Error:

```
TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: '"{%' from '"{%'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the name of the file to include in the [**`{% cycle … %}`** template tag [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#cycle), and assign it to a variable (`tmp` for example). Then you can use that variable in the [**`{% include … %}`** template tag [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#include):

```
{% for variable in loop %}
    {% cycle 'col-1-of-3.html' 'col-2-of-3.html' 'col-3-of-3.html' as tmp silent %}
    {% include tmp %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: TemplateDoesNotExist at /tools-dash/ got this error. Three html files are inside template/tools folder

Comment: @VAsplash: you of course need to specify the correct path to the templates. Django does not look at the files in the same directory. If your directory is `tools`, it should be `tools/col-1-of-3.html` instead (same for the other files of course).

Comment: It worked but for every loop it shows tools/col-1-of-3.html and others in html on each loop

Comment: @VAsplash: ah yes, you need to add `silent` at the end of the `{% cycle %}`.